# Update Label Output when Any Input Changes - VBA Userform

Tags: vba

VBA neophyte here. Here's the code:

```
Dim oper_state As Integer
Dim r As Integer
Dim c As Integer
Dim timehr As Double
Dim timemin As Double

Public Sub UserForm_Initialize()

r = 0
c = 0

AAATemp.Value = ""
LineTemp.Value = ""

Operational.Value = False
Deactivated.Value = False

AAATemp.SetFocus
HOPA.Output.Caption = "Insert Temperature Data"

End Sub

Public Sub Deactivated_Click()

If Deactivated = True Then
    oper_state = 0
End If

End Sub

Public Sub Operational_Click()

If Operational = True Then
    oper_state = 1
End If

End Sub

Public Sub AAATemp_Change()

If AAATemp.Value < 18.3 Then
    r = 3
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 18.3 And AAATemp.Value <= 19.4) Then
    r = 4
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 19.4 And AAATemp.Value <= 20.6) Then
    r = 5
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 20.6 And AAATemp.Value <= 21.7) Then
    r = 6
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 21.7 And AAATemp.Value <= 22.8) Then
    r = 7
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 22.8 And AAATemp.Value <= 23.9) Then
    r = 8
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 23.9 And AAATemp.Value <= 25) Then
    r = 9
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 25 And AAATemp.Value <= 26.1) Then
    r = 10
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 26.1 And AAATemp.Value <= 27.2) Then
    r = 11
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 27.2 And AAATemp.Value <= 28.3) Then
    r = 12
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 28.3 And AAATemp.Value <= 29.4) Then
    r = 13
ElseIf (AAATemp.Value >= 29.4 And AAATemp.Value <= 30.6) Then
    r = 14
Else
    r = 15
End If

If (r = 0 Or c = 0) Then
    HOPA.Output.Caption = "Insert Temperature Data"
ElseIf (oper_state = 1 And r <> 0 And c <> 0) Then
    timehr = Worksheets("HOPA Times").Cells(r, c).Value
    timemin = timehr * 60
    If timehr = 9999 Then
        HOPA.Output.Caption = "Inf"
    ElseIf timehr < 9999 Then
        HOPA.Output.Caption = timehr & " (" & timemin & " minutes)"
    End If
ElseIf (oper_state = 0 And r <> 0 And c <> 0) Then
    r = r + 16
    timehr = Worksheets("HOPA Times").Cells(r, c).Value
    timemin = timehr * 60
    If timehr = 9999 Then
        HOPA.Output.Caption = "Inf"
    ElseIf timehr < 9999 Then
        HOPA.Output.Caption = timehr & " (" & timemin & " minutes)"
    End If
End If

End Sub

Public Sub LineTemp_Change()

If LineTemp.Value < 14.7 Then
    c = 2
ElseIf (LineTemp.Value >= 14.7 And LineTemp.Value <= 15.8) Then
    c = 3
ElseIf (LineTemp.Value >= 15.8 And LineTemp.Value <= 16.9) Then
    c = 4
ElseIf (LineTemp.Value >= 16.9 And LineTemp.Value <= 18) Then
    c = 5
ElseIf (LineTemp.Value >= 18 And LineTemp.Value <= 19.2) Then
    c = 6
ElseIf (LineTemp.Value >= 19.2 And LineTemp.Value <= 20.3) Then
    c = 7
ElseIf (LineTemp.Value >= 20.3 And LineTemp.Value <= 21.4) Then
    c = 8
ElseIf (LineTemp.Value >= 21.4 And LineTemp.Value <= 22.5) Then
    c = 9
ElseIf (LineTemp.Value >= 22.5 And LineTemp.Value <= 23.6) Then
    c = 10
ElseIf (LineTemp.Value >= 23.6 And LineTemp.Value <= 24.7) Then
    c = 11
ElseIf (LineTemp.Value >= 24.7 And LineTemp.Value <= 25.8) Then
    c = 12
Else
    c = 13
End If

If (r = 0 Or c = 0) Then
    HOPA.Output.Caption = "Insert Temperature Data"
ElseIf (oper_state = 1 And r <> 0 And c <> 0) Then
    timehr = Worksheets("HOPA Times").Cells(r, c).Value
    timemin = timehr * 60
    If timehr = 9999 Then
        HOPA.Output.Caption = "Inf"
    ElseIf timehr < 9999 Then
        HOPA.Output.Caption = timehr & " (" & timemin & " minutes)"
    End If
ElseIf (oper_state = 0 And r <> 0 And c <> 0) Then
    r = r + 16
    timehr = Worksheets("HOPA Times").Cells(r, c).Value
    timemin = timehr * 60
    If timehr = 9999 Then
        HOPA.Output.Caption = "Inf"
    ElseIf timehr < 9999 Then
        HOPA.Output.Caption = timehr & " (" & timemin & " minutes)"
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

These values are determined through a UserForm. The UserForm has two radio buttons, two text inputs, and one label (for output). The label changes dynamically based on the radio button selection and the user inputs - at least, that's what I'd like it to do.

Unfortunately, the label output only updates when I make changes to the AAA or LineTemp text boxes. Nothing happens when I click between radio buttons. If I do change a radio button selection, I need to go in and make a change to a textbox input (typically just delete the decimal and re-enter it).

I've tried moving the radio button logic inside the change subs, but obviously that doesn't work. Is there a way to have Excel look at the entire form and check for changes?

Comment: Create an `UpdateLabel` sub and call that from the events for each of the inputs: `UpdateLabel` would read the control values and change the label as needed.

Comment: Got it working doing this. Thanks, Tim.